# Dash doesn't close on click after creating lens with Quickly, what's wrong?

Tags: application-development, quickly, applications-lens

I've used Quickly to create a lens that interacts with another program when that program is executed, using the following function:

```
 def handle_uri(self, scope, uri):  
     os.system(uri)
```

But the dash is not closed on click. How do I remedy this?

Also, is there a list of all the functions or built in 'shortcuts' for quickly?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some digging I found hide_dash_response in the singlet sources...however I was unable to call or return this function without copying the code to my project.

I can also return

```
Unity.ActivationResponse(handled=Unity.HandledType.HIDE_DASH, goto_uri=uri)
```

directly to achieve the same result.